Does TypeScript support default implementation of functions in interfaces
Default implementation of functions that you want in the TypeScript interface
TypeScript Version：5.5.3
Node Version :18.14.2
interface Greeting {
    sayGoodbye(name: string): void = {
      console.log(`Goodbye, ${name}!`);
    };
  }
  class EnglishGreeting implements Greeting {
    sayGoodbye(name: string): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    sayHello(name: string): void {
      console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
    }
  }

If the compilation fails in the above way, whether the interface can support the default implementation of the function

What happens when you try it?  What research have you done?

No, that's not possible. TS's interfaces are erased, they don't exist at runtime at all. See answers to the linked questions above for more information. You're presumably going to need to use class inheritance (possibly via mixins) if you want behavior like this.

Well, the Interfaces must define method signatures without implementations.
Meaning sayGoodbye(name: string): void = {...} is invalid
Method like sayGoodbye(name: string): void is valid.

    interface Greeting {
      sayGoodbye(name: string): void;
    }
    
    class EnglishGreeting implements Greeting {
      sayGoodbye(name: string): void {
        console.log(`Goodbye, ${name}!`);
      }
    
      sayHello(name: string): void {
        console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
      }
    }


